# How to get correct rendering of button next to text field in firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #theInput
            {
                border:solid 1px gray;
                height:20px;
            }
            #theButton
            {   
                border:solid 1px gray;
                height:20px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="theInput"><input type="button" value=" Go " id="theButton">
    <body>
</html>
```

When rendering the previous in Firefox the button is about 1px higher than the text field.  How to fix this?  *With no doctype specified, the heights are perfect in chrome and surprisingly even IE6 but not in Firefox?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a recent DOCTYPE, such as HTML 4.01 or XHTML 1.0 or 1.1, then consistently in FF, Chrome, and IE 8, the button is actually 2 pixels shorter than the text box.  In FF, Firebug actually reports the box being 18px.  So I recommend using a standard compliant DOCTYPE, and also styling the button 2px taller than the text box:

> http://jsfiddle.net/DPbsA/8/

Here is one with an orange box to the left, with height = 20px, and border = 1px top and bottom, making the total "visual height" of the box 22px:

> http://jsfiddle.net/DPbsA/12/

You probably would want to use a standard compliant DOCTYPE, because without them, the box models between FF/Chrome and IE can be quite different.

Comment: Even though it sounds weird in context of a modern DocType: styling the button 2px higher than the textbox to get them equally tall, it is the right answer. voted up.

Answer (score 0):

Its always good to have standard doctype , as IE falls back to quirks mode if you don't specify the doctype.

add the padding-bottom , it will align with the text box

let me know if you need anything else

```
    #theButton
                {   
                    border:solid 1px gray;
                    height:20px;
                    padding-bottom:2px;


}
```